# Recursively Enumerable Languages and Turing Machines

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

L1 = { M | Turing Machine M terminates for at least 637 inputs}
L2 = { M | Turing Machine M terminates for at most 636 inputs}
One of them is recursively enumerable, which one?

Comment: Did you try applying the definition? Did it work? If no, why?

Comment: I didn't. What you mean by that? I am total noob in this and I want to understand how I should approach the problem. I am not bored to work on it, I just do not know how to approach this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A language is said to be recursively enumerable if you can build a Turing machine that accepts all inputs that are in the language (but does not necessarily reject inputs that are not).

The obvious machine you'd want to construct, for both languages, is one that activates $M$ on all possible inputs in a finite time. While this may seem like a too much, it's actually possible, with the following algorithm:

1. Set an order in which you traverse all inputs, call them $(x_i)_{i=0}^\infty$. (This can be, for instance, the alphabetical order)
2. For the $i$th iteration, initialize $M$ and run $i$ steps of it on $\{x_0,\ldots,x_i\}$.

By doing this you guarantee that eventually you'll have run any finite number of steps of $M$ on any input.

Can you use this method to construct a machine that accepts one of $L_1,L_2$?

Comment: No, so that means that L1 is the recursively enumerable language, right?

Comment: It is, but I'm not sure you got my explanation right; to show that $L_1$ is r.e. you have to construct a Turing machine that accepts it, that is: Given a machine $M$, construct a Turing machine (that can use $M$ and the method I described above) that checks whether $M$ terminates on at least $637$ inputs.

Comment: Yes I hadn't. I have to google about how to construct Turing Machines, since I do not know how.

Comment: In this case (I suppose) you can just write the algorithm out in words and ignore the inner workings of a Turing machine. The method I described above allows you to run $M$ for any finite number of steps on all possible inputs; that means that you'll eventually be able to pick out any input for which $M$ terminates in a finite number of steps. Therefore, if there are $637$ of these, the machine will find them in a finite time and be able to accept $M$.

Comment: My intention is not just to solve the problem, but to learn as much as I can, so I will search for constructing Turing machines. If you have a good link, please provide it.

Comment: I just looked at Wikipedia for [Turing Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine), and the informal definition looks pretty good, and I would cite the [Church-Turing Thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) as my "justification" for just writing the algorithm in words (precisely constructing an actual Turing machine can be long and painful). Unfortunately I don't know any more comprehensive online resources, but I recall having studied from a book called "Introduction to the Theory of Computation" by Michael Sipser.

Comment: Ok Alfonso, thank you!